# How to use Rails Web App as ruby script input and output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm new to rails and I'm working on this project:
I have done a ruby script which needs an input and that prints some outputs.
Basically it takes the first *n* decimal digits of PI and then it calculates some stats.
I need to use a rails web app to insert the input, which is a number, and to print the decimal digits and 10 stats rows.

---

This is the ruby script

```rb
require 'bigdecimal/math'
#PI decimals generator
i = 0
j = 0
a_pi = Array.new
print "Insert how many digits do you want to calculate: "
dig_n = gets.chomp.to_i
x = BigMath.PI(dig_n)
a_pi = x.to_s.split('')

begin
  a_pi.shift
  i += 1
end until i == 3

arr_length = a_pi.length

begin
  a_pi.pop
  j += 1
end until j == arr_length - dig_n

pi_dec = a_pi.join.to_i
puts pi_dec
```

I'm using Ruby 2.6 and Rails 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way around. What you want is more "a web app/web form that does something with input". Rails might be too much for your use case. If you are not bound to Rails you might want to look into other / lighter web frameworks in ruby like Sinatra or Hanami. This could help: [Run ruby script from a HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418597/run-ruby-script-from-a-html-form)